# Replace the last 3 business day of month data in dataframe by another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I replace the data of last 3 business day of month(custom calendar) of a dataframe from another?

I am trying to do some data analysis for investment (trading HSI futures to be specific).  There are two dataframes for futures settling in this month (dataframe A) and next month(dataframe B).

The dataframe A look like this

```
Date      Value

2/1/2019    123

3/1/2019    456

...

29/1/2019   785

30/1/2019   424

31/1/2019   456

1/2/2019    484

...

27/2/2019 465 (last day for available data)
```

The dataframe B look like this

```
Date      Value

2/1/2019    654

3/1/2019    424

...

29/1/2019   544

30/1/2019   111

31/1/2019   222

1/2/2019    333

...

27/2/2019   444 (last day for available data)
```

I want to modify dataframe A that, at the last 3 business days of each month. The data should be replaced by the data in dataframe B

i.e.

```
Date      Value

2/1/2019    123

3/1/2019    456

...

29/1/2019   544

30/1/2019   111

31/1/2019   222

1/2/2019    484

...

27/2/2019   444 (last day for data available data)
```

I looked up online and made a custom calendar already(shown below and I remove most of the holiday for simplicity).

I did also manage to modify the data up to last month. 
But if today is one of the 3 last business days, for example if today is 27/2/2019 show above, I don't know how to replace the data from dataframe B (value = 444)

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BMonthEnd
from datetime import date
from pandas.tseries.holiday import AbstractHolidayCalendar, nearest_workday, Holiday
import numpy as np
import quandl

=================Holiday=============================

class hktradingholiday2019(AbstractHolidayCalendar):
    rules = [
        Holiday('New Years Day', year=2019, month=1, day=1, observance=nearest_workday),
    ]

hktradeholiday2019 = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=hktradingholiday2019())

hktradeday2019 = pd.date_range(start="1/1/2019",end="31/12/2019", freq=hktradeholiday2019)

=======================================================

dataframeA = quandl.get("CHRIS/HKEX_HSI1")  
dataframeB = quandl.get("CHRIS/HKEX_HSI2")  

endoflastmonth= dataframeB.index[-1] - pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(1)
df = dataframeB[:endoflastmonth]     
df = df.groupby(df.index.month).tail(3)

dataframeA.loc[df.index] = df
```

Would anyone suggest how could I get the data on 27/2/2019 replaced by the value in Dataframe B?

My first idea is to use if statement to check if the last row is one of the 3 business days (therefore I have done the calendar thingy).  But I dont know how to get it done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
class hktradingholiday2019(AbstractHolidayCalendar):
    rules = [
        Holiday('New Years Day', year=2019, month=1, day=1, observance=nearest_workday),
    ]

hktradeholiday2019 = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=hktradingholiday2019())

hktradeday2019 = pd.date_range(start="1/1/2019",end="31/12/2019", freq=hktradeholiday2019)
print (hktradeday2019)

#create DatetimeIndex
dfA['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfA['Date'], dayfirst=True)
dfB['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfB['Date'], dayfirst=True)

dfA = dfA.set_index('Date')
dfB = dfB.set_index('Date')

#print (dfA)
#print (dfB)
```

---

```
#get last 3 days per months for hktradeday2019    
s = hktradeday2019.to_series()
lastdays = s.groupby(s.index.month).tail(3)
#print (lastdays)

#replace only last 3 month values if exist
#same indices, so is possible assign by same idx in dfAb and dfB
idx = dfA.index.intersection(lastdays.index)
dfA.loc[idx] = dfB.loc[idx].combine_first(dfA.loc[idx])
print (dfA)
            Value
Date             
2019-01-02    123
2019-01-03    456
2019-01-29    544
2019-01-30    111
2019-01-31    222
2019-02-01    484
2019-02-27    444
```

Comment: I cant use .tail(3) because sometimes the datetime index does not end at the 3 last business day of the month.
For example, if the data end at 15/2/2019, the data on 15/2/2019 in dataframe A would be replaced which I dont want

Comment: And dataframe A and B have the same index.

Comment: the dataframe i got now ends at the day 15/2/2019.  I want to replace the data of 29,30,31/1/2019 in dataframe A by the data of 29,30,31/1/2019 in dataframe B. 
If I just simply use lastB = dfB.groupby(dfB.index.month).tail(3)
It will replace my data of 13,14,15/2/2019 in Dataframe A which these 3 days are not the last 3 business day of Feb

Comment: i.e.  in the sample dataframe shown above, I dont want to replace the data of 1/2/2019 in Dataframe A by Dataframe B because 1/2/2019 is not the last 3 business day of feb

Answer (score 0):

To copy data from `A` to `B` you can use:

```
A.mask(criterionlist, B)
```

but the key to success is how to define the above `criterionlist`.

To take account for a custom business calendar, you have to define it.
For demonstration purpose, I prepared such a calendar with *Jan 30* as
a holiday (this date is among dates in the example below):

```
class ExBusinessCalendar(AbstractHolidayCalendar):
    rules = [
        Holiday('New Years Day', month=1, day=1),
        Holiday('My Extra Free Day', month=1, day=30),
        EasterMonday,
        Holiday('Labour Day', month=5, day=1)
    ]
```

Then you have to define the following auxiliary variables, related to
our custom calendar:

- `offset` - An offset to *CustomBusinessMonthEnd*.
- `cbd` - A *CustomBusinessDay* offset.
- `isBusinessDay` - a function checking whether the current date is
  "on offset" (whether it is an actual business day in our calendar).

I introduced the last function as a safeguard to filter out non-business
days if source data included any.

Details how to define them are in the script below.

Having the above variables and both DataFrames, the criterion list can
be expressed as:

```
A.Date.map(lambda d: offset.rollforward(d) <= d + 2 * cbd
    and isBusinessDay(d))
```

This function:

- Computes `offset.rollforward(d)` - the last business day in the
  current month.
- Then computes `d + 2 * cbd` - the current date + 2 business days.
- If the first of the above dates is earlier or equal to the second,
  we are within the range of 3 last business days in the current month.
- Additional, "filtering" criterion is that this date (`d`) must be
  a business day in our calendar. In the example below it filters out
  the row for *2019-01-30*.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.holiday import AbstractHolidayCalendar, Holiday, EasterMonday, Easter

# Example business calendar
class ExBusinessCalendar(AbstractHolidayCalendar):
    rules = [
        Holiday('New Years Day', month=1, day=1),
        Holiday('My Extra Free Day', month=1, day=30),
        EasterMonday,
        Holiday('Labour Day', month=5, day=1)
    ]
# Source data for A and B
datA = [ ['2/1/2019',  120], ['3/1/2019',  450], ['26/1/2019', 760],
    ['27/1/2019', 770], ['28/1/2019', 780], ['29/1/2019', 790],
    ['30/1/2019', 420], ['31/1/2019', 450], ['1/2/2019',  480],
    ['2/2/2019',  480] ]
datB = [ ['2/1/2019',  122], ['3/1/2019',  453], ['26/1/2019', 764],
    ['27/1/2019', 775], ['28/1/2019', 786], ['29/1/2019', 797],
    ['30/1/2019', 428], ['31/1/2019', 451], ['1/2/2019',  482],
    ['2/2/2019',  483] ]

# Create DataFrames
A = pd.DataFrame(data=datA, columns=['Date', 'Value'])
A.Date = pd.to_datetime(A.Date, dayfirst=True)
B = pd.DataFrame(data=datB, columns=['Date', 'Value'])
B.Date = pd.to_datetime(B.Date, dayfirst=True)

# Auxiliary variables
offset = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessMonthEnd(calendar=ExBusinessCalendar())
cbd = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(calendar=ExBusinessCalendar())
isBusinessDay = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(calendar=ExBusinessCalendar()).onOffset
# Compute the result
A.mask(A.Date.map(lambda d: offset.rollforward(d) <= d + 2 * cbd
   and isBusinessDay(d)), B)
```

The result is:

```
        Date  Value
0 2019-01-02    120
1 2019-01-03    450
2 2019-01-26    760
3 2019-01-27    770
4 2019-01-28    786
5 2019-01-29    797
6 2019-01-30    420
7 2019-01-31    451
8 2019-02-01    480
9 2019-02-02    480
```

As you can see, values copied from `B` are for *2019-01-28*, *2019-01-29*
and *2019-01-31* (in my example data they do not have *0* at the end).

Value for *2019-01-30* has not been copied, as in my custom business calendar
it is not a business day.

To modify `A` with the above result, change the last instruction to:

```
A = A.mask(A.Date.map( ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  
May I ask how can BusinessMonthEnd take customized holiday into account?

Comment: I replaced my previous answer with a new solution, taking into account a custom business calendar.